# Understanding the Tensorflow MNIST tutorial - Is the input x a column matrix or an array of column matrices?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, mnist

I am following the [Tensorflow MNIST tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html).

Reading through the theoretical / intuition section, I came to understand `x`, the input, as being a column matrix.

In fact, when describing `softmax`, `x` is shown as a column matrix:

[image: softmax intuition, with x clearly being shown as a column matrix]

However, declared in `tensorflow`, x looks like this:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
```

I read this a `x` being an array of variable length ( None ) with each element of this array being a column matrix of size 784.

Even though `x` is declared as an array of column matrices, it is used as if it was just a column matrix:

```
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
```

In the example, `W` and `b` are declared intuitivly, as variables of shape `[784, 10]` and `[10]` respectivly, which makes sense.

My questions are:

1. Does Tensorflow automatically perform the softmax operation for each column matrix in x?
2. Am I correct in assuming [None, value] means, intuitivly, an array of variable size with each element being an array of size value? Or is it possible for [None, value] to also mean just an array of size value? ( without it being in a container array )
3. What is the correct way to link the theoretical description, where x is a column vector to the implementation, where x is an array of column matrices?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A question that had confused me for days! Added my interpretation in the answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intuition is for a single input sample (and that's why you see a column vector). In practice however, training is done using mini-batches which consist of a number of input samples. (depending on the `batch_size`).

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
```

This line makes a matrix of dimensions `? x 784` where `?` will denote the batch size. the column vectors in a sense have become the rows of this new matrix.

Since we've converted our column vector into rows, we interchange the order of multiplication of `x` and `W`. This is why your `W` has a dimension of `784 x 10` and `b` has a dimension `10` which will apply on all elements.
After the first multiplication, `x*W` has a dimension `? x 10`. The same element `b` is added to every row of `x*W`. So if my first row of `x*W` is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]` and `b` is `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`, the first row of the resultant will be `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1]`. If you are finding it very hard to understand, try taking a transpose of `W*x`.

Coming to your questions,

> Does Tensorflow automatically perform the softmax operation for each column matrix in x?

Yes, in your context. TensorFlow applies the `softmax` across all elements of dimension `1` (all the rows in my interpretation above). So your resulting `softmax` result will also have dimension `? x 10`.

> Am I correct in assuming [None, value] means, intuitivly, an array of variable size with each element being an array of size value? Or is it possible for [None, value] to also mean just an array of size value? ( without it being in a container array )

Yes, the former is the correct interpretation. Also look at my `?` matrix analogy above.

> What is the correct way to link the theoretical description, where x is a column vector to the implementation, where x is an array of column matrices?

I personally interpret this like a transpose of `W*x`. Elaborating, let `x` be a number of column vectors, `[x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 ...]` having dimension `784 x ?` where `?` is the batch size. Let `W` have a dimension `10 x 784`. If you apply `W` on each column, you will get `[W*x1 W*x2 W*x3...]` or a number of column vectors of dimension `10`, giving a net matrix dimension `10 x ?`.

Take the transpose of this entire operation, `trans(W*x) = trans(x)*trans(W)`, which are the `x` and `W` in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I'll check the matrix transpose like you said. It does make sense with the rows. And I suppose this would also relate to how the output looks, a matrix of probabilities per class.

Comment: I hope it helped you. Do comment here if something unclear and don't forget to accept this as a correct answer if it helped

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it does make sense now. The reason I am going through this again is, I want to get a very solid intuition of what is going on so I can adapt the model. I want to change the model to work with the actual 28x28 matrix instead of a squeezed vector. I'm still not sure how this would change the way the weights and biases look. Do you have any suggestions regarding this? Essentially, I want to change the model to weight the edges of the 28x28 matrix less than the center.

Comment: Perhaps you could start with inputs of dimension `? x 28 x 28` and multiply each element of array of dimension `?` with a certain filter of dimension `28 x 28` reducing the high values at the edges before the actual squeeze? I'm sure this is do-able using a `numpy` function, perhaps a certain form of `numpy.dot`?

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Thanks for the suggestion!